# How to have automatic function parameter hint popup in NeoVim ( LunarVim ) with pyright LSP?

Tags: neovim, lsp, lunarvim, pyright

**Greetings**

> NeoVim version: NVIM v0.9.5.

I have recently installed NeoVim, with [**LunarVim**](https://www.lunarvim.org/) configuration on top.

My LSP is Pyright.

Everything about the LSP and configuration is great, but everytime I'm calling a function I have to press `CTRL+K` for the function parameters to be visualized, is there any way to make the hint window pop up automatically ( even while passing function arguments )?

**config.lua file content:**

```
-- Sets up the plugins.
lvim.plugins = {
  { "LunarVim/onedarker.nvim", "olimorris/onedarkpro.nvim", "akinsho/toggleterm.nvim", "sindrets/diffview.nvim", "fannheyward/coc-pyright", "davidhalter/jedi", "akinsho/toggleterm.nvim", "pwntester/octo.nvim", "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim", "roobert/bufferline-cycle-windowless.nvim", 'tamton-aquib/staline.nvim', "utilyre/barbecue.nvim"},
  {
    "stevearc/dressing.nvim",
    config = function()
      require("dressing").setup({
        input = { enabled = false },
      })
    end,
  },
  {
    "nvim-neorg/neorg",
    ft = "norg", -- lazy-load on filetype
    config = true, -- run require("neorg").setup()
  },
}


-- Sets up code runner binding
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>r', ':RunCode<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rf', ':RunFile<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rft', ':RunFile tab<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rp', ':RunProject<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rc', ':RunClose<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>crf', ':CRFiletype<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>crp', ':CRProjects<CR>', { noremap = true, silent = false })


-- Sets up file viewer logic.
-- disable netrw at the very start of your init.lua
vim.g.loaded_netrw = 1
vim.g.loaded_netrwPlugin = 1

-- set termguicolors to enable highlight groups
vim.opt.termguicolors = true

-- empty setup using defaults
require("nvim-tree").setup()

-- OR setup with some options
require("nvim-tree").setup({
  sort = {
    sorter = "case_sensitive",
  },
  view = {
    width = 30,
  },
  renderer = {
    group_empty = true,
  },
  filters = {
    dotfiles = true,
  },
})


-- Sets up statusline style.
lvim.builtin.lualine.style = "default"


-- Sets up tabline logic.
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<S-l>"] = "<CMD>BufferLineCycleWindowlessNext<CR>"
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<S-h>"] = "<CMD>BufferLineCycleWindowlessPrev<CR>"
lvim.keys.normal_mode["<S-t>"] = "<CMD>BufferLineCycleWindowlessToggle<CR>"


-- Sets up the language server.
local pyright_opts = {
  single_file_support = true,
  settings = {
    pyright = {
      disableLanguageServices = false,
      disableOrganizeImports = false
    },
    python = {
      analysis = {
        autoImportCompletions = true,
        autoSearchPaths = true,
        diagnosticMode = "workspace", -- openFilesOnly, workspace
        typeCheckingMode = "basic", -- off, basic, strict
        useLibraryCodeForTypes = true
      }
    }
  },
}




vim.cmd("color onedark")
require("lvim.lsp.manager").setup("pyright", pyright_opts)
```